# В каком порядке лучше производить верстку?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Эффективнее сначала производить HTML разметку, назначать классы блокам, а потом уже переключаться на css и стилизовать все это дело? или выгоднее после разметки каждого блока прописывать его стили в css?

Answer (score 2):

Я верстаю в HTML основные блоки, потом назначаю им разметку, которая их позиционирует, потом верстаю более мелкие блоки и позиционирую их, потом занимаюсь украшательством. А потом все в любом случае превращается в тыкву :)

Answer (score 2):

Зависит от исходных данных думаю. В любом случае системный подход это хорошо, он отнимает больше времени в начале, но меньше в конце. [Спаггети](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4) подход - экономит время в начале, но убивает в ноль его в конце. Если у Вас разовый проект  -  сделал и забыл - то эффективнее [спаггети](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4), если проект будет развиваться - только системный подход.

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от того, кто Вы, кем себя ощущаете на данный момент времени и чем занимаетесь.

Есть такие спецы, которым дают картинки, ворох сопроводиловки и назначают время- отсюда, и до обеда, и чтоб попиксельно. И так каждый рабочий день. Вот тут нарабатывается четкий порядок действий и методика решений тех или иных задач. Получил такой человек-функция набор параметров- обработал, вернул.

Есть эдакие "юноши с горящими глазами", чем они занимаются, занимались до написания вот этого блока кода, что будут делать после- вопросы крайне неверные да и для них самих непонятные. Там над одним дивом может происходить недельная медитация, или с полчетвертого до пяти родиться оригинальный проект с некислой начинкой, может раз тцать смениться какой-нибудь фреймворк, или ... Художники одним словом. Но зато у них есть идея, нет, Идея, образ, который они видят и пытаются реализовать всеми доступными средствами. А если не видят, очень переживают.

А истина, наверное, где-то посередине.